# Library to create GUIs based on connectable boxes?

Tags: library, user-interface

I have a software idea I'd like to prototype: a tool that generates source code (probably C++, maybe C#), based on the logic described in boxes that the user can connect or re-arrange.

I would use it to wrap an API that requires a combination of boilerplate code blocks to be written every time. Instead of tediously writing redundant code, the user could use the graphical editor to set what is needed in the API.

To try out that idea, I am looking for a GUI library that allows to manipulate blocks, connect them and edit their contents (mostly adding combo boxes, check boxes, and the occasional text box to the building blocks). I am not settled on the language of the tool, something that could work with a minimum of additions would be fine.
Any suggestions?

Comment: That kind of reminds me of scratch. It dosen't generate source code, but might be a start.

Comment: StarUML has an add-on menu entry "Tools/C++/Generate Code...", but I have never used it. Maybe worth checking